# Unable to establish SSL connection (Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, cmd.exe, ssl, wget

I am trying to run the following command in Command Prompt on Windows, using GNU Wget 1.11.4:

```
wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd https://www.ceratizit.com/
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2021-07-07 10:03:45--  https://www.ceratizit.com/                                                                     Resolving www.ceratizit.com... 2.16.128.209, 2.16.128.225
Connecting to www.ceratizit.com|2.16.128.209|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

The same command works on linux but not on Windows. What can I try?

Comment: Your wget version is pretty old (most likely this is the 2008 version that can be found on sourceforge) and does only support outdated SSL/TLS versions. I strongly recommend to no longer use such old versions because of multiple vulnerabilities in wget and openssl.

Comment: Install WSL or WSL2 for Windows and a recent WSL Linux distribution like Ubuntu then you will get a recent version of wget that can be used in Windows.

Comment: [Updated `wget` for Windows builds](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) (no WSL/Cygwin).

Answer (score 1):

this error usually comes up if the protocol versions don't match. For example if your server uses TLS1.2 and the client tries to use TLS1.0. -> This would only work if the server is backwards compatible, otherwise you'll see the message that you posted.
Whenever you connect to your server, the software behind it expects the so called 'ServerHello'. It can also happen if the server doesn't support SSL at all.

As you stated, that it's working with Linux, check which Protocol your Windows machine is using. This is also suggested by the ':unknown protocol' string in the message that you posted.

Additional debug options:

- You can try to use wget with the option --no-check-certificate
- Further debugging would be to request the SSL-connection via it's port. You can do this via wget http://>server<:443 -> If this works, you need to enable SSL on the 443 port. Otherwise wget doesn't offer too much debugging information, so you'd need to use something more sophisticated like f.e. the openssl client in combination with it's debug option.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: A quick search brought up the topic in an older post: [Stackoverflow - Unable to establish SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert)

Comment: For --no-check-certificate, I still get the same error and for ```wget http://>server<:443``` I get that the syntax is invalid? Was I supposed to run it as it is?

Comment: @x89 See Robert's comment under your question, as the `wget` version is likely the issue _(why are you using software that's [13yrs old](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/) - update it and the issue will likely resolve due to the issue Robert mentioned)_

Comment: @syseng21 TLS v1.0 came out in 1999 and was depreciated 03/2020, so no client should be using it or v1.1 [depreciated 03/2020], and all updated software supports TLS v1.2 or higher. The whole point of an SSL/TLS connection is to ensure the data being received is secure, so `--no-check-certificate` isn't really a solution, as the user may as well use an HTTP link in that case.